# Interview Q: A sum of digits time 3 equal itself

Tags: math, integer

I had a phone interview. And one of the question was

> There is a number and the sum of its digits 3 times equals to the number
>   itself and there is only one such number. Which is this number?

I had no idea how to approach this question. And asked for hints. They wouldn't give any and I was lost to what the number could be.

Now how should someone like me with limited amount of information approach this question with given information (assuming they didn't tell me how many digits was in the number)?

Comment: Conjecture. Experiment. If I told you the number has exactly `2` digits, what would you do? If I told you the number has exactly `3` digits, what would you do? Can you make any hypotheses? Can you test them? Can you prove them?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about coding.

Comment: I would ask "Which one of 0 and the other number do you mean?"

Comment: @Ingo Ah right.  Silly me, I would have trusted their claim that "*there is only one such number*" and stop at zero, never finding 27.

Comment: @AakashM yes i thought about it after that if it's 2 digit then 10x+y = 3(x+y) if it's 3 digit then would be 100z+10x+y = 3(z+x+y) which is not solvable and need more information. I complete froze during the interview thou :(

Comment: What an utterly stupid interview question.

Comment: You thought right: 10x + y = 3x + 3y, 10x = 3x + 2y, 7x = 2y : and here it gets clear that x=2 and y = 7 is a solution.

Comment: And then after the Interviewer told me that 27 was also a solution to their question (that had only one answer), I would look for employment somewhere else.

Comment: @user1655072 next time remember that when you are asked such a question in an interview, they're not looking for *the answer* (they know the answer!) - they're want to *see you think*. Let them see that!

Comment: The problem is that my *thinking* would be that they were incompetent to ask such a question.

Comment: I understand the question might be better in mathematica or programmers section. If the question is not in anyway useful please remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number is 10x + y then 10x + y = 3(x+ y) --> x/y = 2/7
So the most obvious solution is x = 2 , y = 7...hence 27 is an answer

Comment: if y=0 then you are dividing by zero..

Comment: Yes, @sara, hence we now y != 0

Comment: 5 minute after my answer when you are sure is two digit and when my answer is already well stated is easy to assume the answer is 27. I don't know how @user1655072 accepted this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would imagine an on the spot question on a phone interview like this would be very challenging.  However, that will also help you solve the question.  Think of small numbers that are multiples of three.  12, 1+2=3 3X3=9 not right, then keep going until: 27, 2+7=9, 9*3 = 27 bingo!  A lot of times we are looking for your thought process as much as being able to find the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This number cannot have more than two digits, because if it has n> 2 digits, then maximum sum of its digits is n*9 and n*9*3 < 10^(n-1). So you should just search among two digit numbers (1 digit is simply not possible). Also it should be divisible by 3, now your search is limited to less than 30 numbers. Also it should be divisible by 9 (why?), so simply you can say is 27 (is not 18, and 27 is correct answer, and by knowing that there is only one number, this is the solution).

Comment: 1 digit is possible: 0

Comment: @Ingo, I think when we talk about numbers we usually talk about natural numbers. (otherwise question is wrong).

Comment: Sure, and if we believe Peano and Frege, 0 is the first natural number.

Comment: But anyway, +1 for good reasoning!

Comment: No, if "*We*" are either mathematicians or programmers we most certainly do *not* mean counting numbers only when we say "Numbers".  As people who work with numbers professionally we would use the correct terms and qualifications.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, It's not my definition is most acceptable definition, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number, there is some discussions about this, and as a computer scientist I like starting with one, but also, from question definition is clear they mean starting from 1, otherwise question is wrong (there is exactly one such a number).

Comment: No, it *is* your definition because the question did *NOT* ask about the "natural numbers".  You added that part.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, So you can suppose they are real number, then provide your answer, my assumption seems to be correct, if you think not, then provide better answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Depending on the field, mathematicians use different definitions (which is ok). Usually, N = 0,1,2,3,.... and N*= 1,2,34,.... Therefore, in an interview, I would ask exactly what kind of number they mean.

Comment: @Ingo, Also you should note that if you want to write a standard zero base you should write N_0. I mean if I was going to have such an interview, at first I'd say seems your position is not fit to my abilities.

Answer (score 0):

A python brute force solution, it may not be the best but it's something.

```
def sum_digits(n):
    s = 0
    while n:
        s += n % 10
        n /= 10
    return s


for i in range(1, 1000):
    if i == sum_digits(i) * 3:
        print i
```